# Rails callback before_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form from where I take one value. Now I need to copy this value to another value in the record. I was trying to use before save for it, but it does not seem to work.

Controller code:

```
@new_performance = PerformanceType.new(params[:id])
@new_performance.save
```

Model Code:

```
def before_save(record)
  record.new_p_type = Thread.current[:old_p_type]
end
```

When I do this it still shows `new_p_type` is NULL when I try and save it. Any pointers what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using the before_save callback, here is an example:

```
before_save :copy_attr

def copy_attr
  self.copy_of_attribute = self.attribute_to_copy
end
```

You can learn more at: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: I am little confused, I have been trying to use the before_save call back itself. But I dont get the way you are doing it? Could u let me know if i m doing something wrong here?

Comment: Never Mind I got what you mean :) Thanks

Comment: Just a follow up question, if I want to copy only if its a new record, would it be the if condition?

Comment: if its only for a new record, you can use before_create, this one is executed only on creation (there are ways to know if the record is new, like comparing create_date vs update_date, but i recommend using before_create)